# Can webpack only print emmited files info while webpack rebuilt?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, webpack-hmr, webpack-hot-middleware, webpack-dev-middleware

**I have use these package to comply webpack HMR:**

- webpack@2.2.1
- webpack-dev-middleware@1.10.1
- webpack-hot-middleware@2.17.1

**webpack stats config:**

```
stats: {
    assetsSort: 'name',
    children: false,
    chunks: false,
    colors: true,
    warnings: false
  }
```

**use webpack-dev-middleware**

```
const _devMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware')(_compiler, {
  publicPath: _webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  stats: _webpackConfig.stats
});
```

Everytime when I run command `npm run dev`, the console will print assets info like:

```
              scripts/app.bundle.js  1.03 MB  50, 100  [emitted]  [big]  app
           scripts/c-actionsheet.js  28.1 kB  61, 100  [emitted]         c-actionsheet
              scripts/c-alphabet.js   110 kB  55, 100  [emitted]         c-alphabet
                  scripts/c-back.js  18.8 kB  46, 100  [emitted]         c-back
                 scripts/c-basic.js   107 kB  74, 100  [emitted]         c-basic
            scripts/c-build-list.js    30 kB  89, 100  [emitted]         c-build-list
         scripts/c-building-info.js  44.4 kB  83, 100  [emitted]         c-building-info
```

but when I use webpack HMR to rebuild the file that I have changed, the console will print the all assets info, include emmited files and unrelated files, just like:

```
                scripts/app.bundle.js   1.03 MB  50, 100  [emitted]  [big]  app
             scripts/c-actionsheet.js   28.1 kB  61, 100                    c-actionsheet
                scripts/c-alphabet.js    110 kB  55, 100                    c-alphabet
                    scripts/c-back.js   18.8 kB  46, 100                    c-back
                   scripts/c-basic.js    107 kB  74, 100                    c-basic
```

I just want to know about the files I've changed, and I don't care about unrelated files info.

**So, Can you help me to let webpack only print these emmited files info ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the option `stats.cachedAssets` to `false`. With that it only shows the assets that are actually emitted. It doesn't seem to be documented but here is the [responsible source line](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/4b9b660e8c4fe8ab6425014cb24dcec2d5df194b/lib/Stats.js#L206) and the [definition of showCachedAssets](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/4b9b660e8c4fe8ab6425014cb24dcec2d5df194b/lib/Stats.js#L64).

Your stats configuration will be:

```
stats: {
    assetsSort: 'name',
    cachedAssets: false,
    children: false,
    chunks: false,
    colors: true,
    warnings: false
}
```

---

The option is now documented at [Configuration - Stats](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/#stats).

Comment: Yeah! `stats.cachedAssets` is what I want. Thank you for your help